# How to recreate a low shutter speed effect on 1/10000 footage?

Tags: ffmpeg, motion

My Sony CX405 is a small miracle of technology but the designers have put a lot of effort on making sure it has some strict limitations, so they do not interfere with the market demand for more expensive models. One of those limitations is the impossibility to adjust a filter. As a result of that, you cannot avoid an absurdly short exposure time (like 1/10000 s) when recording outdoors on a sunny day and the resulting footage of moving objects has that broken, stroboscopic look that ruins the smooth experience of 60i video.

Is there any software that can take that footage and emulate a low shutter speed by directionally blurring only the moving parts?

Comment: Perhaps an alternative, maybe a firmware update can give you the control you want. Note though, chances are good such an act violates your warranty.

Comment: @DigiVisionMedia The camera already allows you to set manually parameters like aperture, shutter speed and so on (though those options are buried in submenus you have to navigate with a small joystick, which conveniently discourages any advanced usage). The problem is, the CMOS is too sensitive for daylight, and if you force a low shutter speed then the iris will automatically close to a tiny hole, blurring the image because of diffraction. The only way around it would be a filter, i.e. a piece of dark glass on top of the lens. They have taken good care to make it impossible to adjust one.

Comment: There's no ND filters?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the camera has no (suitable?) filter thread, you should be able to fix some Cokin filter holder to a flash bracket.  While I cannot vouch for ready made solutions here, I should be surprised if you cannot combine a few stock components.  The main problem of course when using such a contraption on an ND filter is to prevent side glare.  You might need to work with some light-proof drapings or stuff.  It may be feasible with a flash bracket or similar (macro bracket?) to move the filter right up to the camera, greatly reducing the problem.